# c++ threading: cv.notify_one() blocks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, mingw-w64, condition-variable

I wrote the following structure to implement a simple single producer / multi consumer synchronization. I'm using two integers `available_index` and `consumed_index`, access to `consumed_index` is protected by the condition variable `cv`. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

struct ParserSync {
    std::mutex worker_lock;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    int consumed_index = -1;
    int available_index = -1;
    bool exit_flag = false;

    int consume_index() {
        int ret = -1;

        // get worker_lock
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> w_lock(worker_lock);

        // wait for exit_flag or new available index
        cv.wait(w_lock, [this] { return exit_flag || available_index > consumed_index; });

        if (available_index > consumed_index) {
            consumed_index++;
            ret = consumed_index;
        }

        // Unlock mutex and notify another thread
        w_lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();

        return ret;
    }

    void publish_index() {
        available_index++;
        std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
        cv.notify_one();
        std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
    }

    void set_exit() {
        exit_flag = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    }
};
```

I tested my implementation using the following code (just a simple example to show the problem):

```
void producer(ParserSync &ps){
    for (int i=0;i<5000;i++){
        ps.publish_index();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
    ps.set_exit();
    std::cout << "Producer finished!" << std::endl;
}

void consumer(ParserSync &ps){
    while (true){
        int idx = ps.consume_index();
        if (idx == -1)
            break;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4));
    }
    std::cout << "Consumer finished!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    ParserSync ps{};
    const int num_consumers = 4;
    std::vector<std::thread> consumer_threads(num_consumers);

    // start consumers
    for (int i = 0; i < num_consumers; ++i) {
        consumer_threads[i] = std::thread{consumer, std::ref(ps)};
    }
    // start producer
    std::thread producer_thread = std::thread{producer, std::ref(ps)};

    for (int i = 0; i < num_consumers; ++i) {
        consumer_threads[i].join();
    }
    producer_thread.join();
    std::cout << "Program finished" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that **producer** thread produces 5000 indices and exits afterwards, but unfortunately, it **gets stuck at some random iteration**. I used print statements to find the code line that blocks and tracked it down to `cv.notify_one();`. This is the (shortened) console output:

```
...
before
after
before
after
before
```

Does anyone know why the call to `cv.notify_one();` blocks?

I'm using MinGW (x86_64-6.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1) on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

When compiling the exact same code with Visual Studio, the program works as expected and doesn't lock itself up. Unfortunately, I need to use MinGW for other reasons.

Comment: Not looked at it in detail, but you should also protect the other shared variables (`available_index`, `exit_flag`) with a mutex before setting. Otherwise the changes might not even be visible to other threads.

Comment: `available_index` and `exit_flag` are only modified by the producer thread and consumers reading "old" values do not cause any problems. And even if the changes weren't visible to the other threads, the producer thread should still complete without freezing at some point

Comment: It causes a problem if they never get visible, since `cv.wait()` will then block forever.

Comment: Or no, it will wake up once due to notify, see no changed values, block again and then possibly never wake up again.

Comment: The `producer` is the one that gets locked/freezes, and there's no `cv.wait()` in it's code. You are talking about the `consumer` threads which aren't the problem here.

Comment: I know it's not the symptom that you have described. But it should be fixed anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't get your point... Both variables (available_index and exit_flag) are only modified by one thread (the producer) and after they are modified, this thread calls notify_one to wake up one of the consumer threads. This woken up thread is guaranteed to read the updated value, isn't it?

Comment: No it isn't due to the memory model of CPUs. It's complicated, but the short version is that if there is no explicit memory barrier the CPU is not obligated to write back the (probably locally cashed) version into the shared Cache or RAM and the other CPU cores might never see it. The question is whether `notify_one` generates a suitable memory barrier that prevents instruction reordering and forces the write back. I'm not sure, but I wouldn't count on it and either put the shared variables under a lock or make them atomic.

Comment: Ok thanks for that clarification.